# Downvotes on Splatoon2 questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

This was mysteriously instantly downvoted,

[What are the rules for the "fresh" (?) score on Splatoon2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350674/what-are-the-rules-for-the-fresh-score-on-splatoon2)

And another Splatoon2 question I posted was mysteriously instantly downvoted,

Is Splatoon2 off topic or?

Is there some other etiquette on this SE site I don't know about?

Is it just a coincidence, new SE users who don't know what they're doing?

Any ideas?  Cheers

Comment: I recently write a question and also instantly got downvoted. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it is sitting with a score of 1, so some people seem to have upvoted this.

Users downvote for a variety of reasons, all of which are unique to them. There are no rules pertaining to certain games being off-topic. There IS etiquette, but again, users are free to downvote anything they think is a low quality question and they don't have to validate their votes.

Your question is okay - if you want to improve it, you could include research links to show that you have researched a bit into it and tried to solve it but couldn't.

Comment: I guess you're right Fox, and indeed since then there's been a few random upvotes also.  Cheers!